# Checking validity of query string before performing SQL filtering of detailsview

Tags: asp.net, sql, query-string, detailsview

Is there anyway to check the validity of a query string before performing SQL data filtering. I mean my detailsview page is expecting a querystring with numeric values, however, if someone tries to send string or huge number or any invalid data the page will crush!! Even if you send a valid data of a record that doesn't exist anymore the page will still be accessible.
I need to enable users to access that page only if there is data display, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Regex to match Querystring pattern as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In the Page_Load event you check the query string with the `IsNumeric()` function or any other pattern matching methods(Regex, etc...) and if it does not pass then Redirect to a diff page.